# Include properties passing a string parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In ef6 using system.data.entity you could dynamically construct .Include queries as follows (very useful in a generic repository)

```
IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet; //some instance of DbSet<TEntity>
query = query.Include("OrderItems");
```

However microsoft.data.entity as of ef7 RC1 doesn't have a .Include extension method that supports that.  Is there another way to achieve this? 
A generic repository without the ability to load related entities through navigation properties is not very useful.

Comment: The same question is here too:  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3921

Comment: I found a solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312437/can-a-string-based-include-alternative-be-created-in-entity-framework-core/38415886#38415886