# Can a string-based Include alternative be created in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

On an API I need dynamic include, but EF Core does not support string-based include.

Because of this, I created a mapper which maps strings to lambda expressions added to a list as:

```cs
List<List<Expression>> expressions = new List<List<Expression>>();
```

Consider the following specific types:

```cs
public class EFContext 
{
    public DbSet<P1> P1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<P1> P2s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<P1> P3s { get; set; }
}

public class P1 
{
    public P2 P2 { get; set; }
    public P3 P3 { get; set; }
}

public class P2 
{
    public P3 P3 { get; set; }
}

public class P3 { }
```

`Include` and `ThenInclude` are normally used as follows:

```cs
EFContext efcontext = new EFContext();
IQueryable<P1> result = efcontext.P1s
        .Include(p1 => p1.P2)
        .ThenInclude(p2 => p2.P3)
        .Include(p1 => p1.P3);
```

They can also be used the following way:

```cs
Expression<Func<P1, P2>> p1p2 = p1 => p1.P2;
Expression<Func<P1, P3>> p1p3 = p1 => p1.P3;
Expression<Func<P2, P3>> p2p3 = p2 => p2.P3;

List<List<Expression>> expressions = new List<List<Expression>> 
    {
        new List<Expression> { p1p2, p1p3 },
        new List<Expression> { p2p3 }
    };

EFContext efcontext = new EFContext();

IIncludableQueryable<P1, P2> q1 = EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions
            .Include(efcontext.P1s, p1p2);
    
IIncludableQueryable<P1, P3> q2 = EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions
            .ThenInclude(q1, p2p3);

IIncludableQueryable<P1, P3> q3 = EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions
            .Include(q2, p1p3);

result = q3.AsQueryable();
```

The problem is that my method receives a list of Expressions and I only have the base type in T:

```
public static class IncludeExtensions<T> 
{
    public static IQueryable<T> IncludeAll(this IQueryable<T> collection, List<List<Expression>> expressions) 
    {
        MethodInfo include = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions)
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .GetDeclaredMethods(nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include))
            .Single(mi => mi.GetParameters()
                .Any(pi => pi.Name == "navigationPropertyPath"));

        MethodInfo includeAfterCollection = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions)
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .GetDeclaredMethods(nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ThenInclude))
            .Single(mi => 
                !mi.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments[1].IsGenericParameter);

        MethodInfo includeAfterReference = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions)
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .GetDeclaredMethods(nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ThenInclude))
            .Single(mi => mi.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments[1].IsGenericParameter);

        foreach (List<Expression> path in expressions) 
        {
            bool start = true;

            foreach (Expression expression in path) 
            {
                if (start) 
                {
                    MethodInfo method = include.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), ((LambdaExpression)expression).ReturnType);

                    IIncludableQueryable<T,?> result = method.Invoke(null, new Object[] { collection, expression });

                    start = false;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    MethodInfo method = includeAfterReference.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), typeof(?), ((LambdaExpression)expression).ReturnType);

                    IIncludableQueryable <T,?> result = method.Invoke(null, new Object[] { collection, expression });
                }           
            }
        }
        
        return collection; // (to be replaced by final as Queryable)
    }
}
```

The main problem has been resolving the correct types for each `Include` and `ThenInclude` step and also which `ThenInclude` to use.

Is this even possible with the current EF7 Core? Did someone find a solution for dynamic `Include`?

The [Include](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/78476005b30ff201d4523d24da090ce6c84fb248/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2227) and [ThenIncludeAfterReference](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/78476005b30ff201d4523d24da090ce6c84fb248/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2340) and [ThenIncludeAfterCollection](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/78476005b30ff201d4523d24da090ce6c84fb248/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2291) methods are part of [EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/78476005b30ff201d4523d24da090ce6c84fb248/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs) class in [EntityFramework Github's](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework) repository.

Comment: Can you provide more context? How are you building these expression lists, why they are list of lists, are they always single property accessor lambdas etc. Or better some sample of the strings that you are processing - like "P2.P3" and "P3" or?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update:**

Starting with v1.1.0, the string based include is now part of EF Core, so the issue and the below solution are obsolete.

**Original answer:**

Interesting exercise for the weekend.

**Solution:**

I've ended up with the following extension method:

```
public static class IncludeExtensions
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo IncludeMethodInfo = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions).GetTypeInfo()
        .GetDeclaredMethods(nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include)).Single(mi => mi.GetParameters().Any(pi => pi.Name == "navigationPropertyPath"));

    private static readonly MethodInfo IncludeAfterCollectionMethodInfo = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions).GetTypeInfo()
        .GetDeclaredMethods(nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ThenInclude)).Single(mi => !mi.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments[1].IsGenericParameter);

    private static readonly MethodInfo IncludeAfterReferenceMethodInfo = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions).GetTypeInfo()
        .GetDeclaredMethods(nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ThenInclude)).Single(mi => mi.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments[1].IsGenericParameter);

    public static IQueryable<TEntity> Include<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, params string[] propertyPaths)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
        object query = source;
        foreach (var propertyPath in propertyPaths)
        {
            Type prevPropertyType = null;
            foreach (var propertyName in propertyPath.Split('.'))
            {
                Type parameterType;
                MethodInfo method;
                if (prevPropertyType == null)
                {
                    parameterType = entityType;
                    method = IncludeMethodInfo;
                }
                else
                {
                    parameterType = prevPropertyType;
                    method = IncludeAfterReferenceMethodInfo;
                    if (parameterType.IsConstructedGenericType && parameterType.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1)
                    {
                        var elementType = parameterType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
                        var collectionType = typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
                        if (collectionType.IsAssignableFrom(parameterType))
                        {
                            parameterType = elementType;
                            method = IncludeAfterCollectionMethodInfo;
                        }
                    }
                }
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(parameterType, "e");
                var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
                if (prevPropertyType == null)
                    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(entityType, property.Type);
                else
                    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(entityType, parameter.Type, property.Type);
                query = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { query, Expression.Lambda(property, parameter) });
                prevPropertyType = property.Type;
            }
        }
        return (IQueryable<TEntity>)query;
    }
}
```

**Test:**

*Model:*

```
public class P
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

public class P1 : P
{
    public P2 P2 { get; set; }
    public P3 P3 { get; set; }
}

public class P2 : P
{
    public P4 P4 { get; set; }
    public ICollection<P1> P1s { get; set; }
}

public class P3 : P
{
    public ICollection<P1> P1s { get; set; }
}

public class P4 : P
{
    public ICollection<P2> P2s { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<P1> P1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<P2> P2s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<P3> P3s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<P4> P4s { get; set; }

    // ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<P1>().HasOne(e => e.P2).WithMany(e => e.P1s).HasForeignKey("P2Id").IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<P1>().HasOne(e => e.P3).WithMany(e => e.P1s).HasForeignKey("P3Id").IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<P2>().HasOne(e => e.P4).WithMany(e => e.P2s).HasForeignKey("P4Id").IsRequired();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
var db = new MyDbContext();

// Sample query using Include/ThenInclude
var queryA = db.P3s
    .Include(e => e.P1s)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.P2)
            .ThenInclude(e => e.P4)
    .Include(e => e.P1s)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.P3);

// The same query using string Includes
var queryB = db.P3s
    .Include("P1s.P2.P4", "P1s.P3");
```

**How it works:**

Given a type `TEntity` and a string property path of the form `Prop1.Prop2...PropN`, we split the path and do the following:

For the first property we just call via reflection the `EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include` method:

```
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty>
Include<TEntity, TProperty>
(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> source,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath
)
```

and store the result. We know `TEntity` and `TProperty` is the type of the property.

For the next properties it's a bit more complex. We need to call one of the following `ThenInclude` overloads:

```
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty>
ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>
(
    this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, ICollection<TPreviousProperty>> source,
    Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath
)
```

and

```
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty>
ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>
(
    this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> source,
    Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath
)
```

`source` is the current result. `TEntity` is one and the same for all calls. But what is `TPreviousProperty` and how we decide which method to call.

Well, first we use a variable to remember what was the `TProperty` in the previous call. Then we check if it is a collection property type, and if yes, we call the first overload with `TPreviousProperty` type extracted from the generic arguments of the collection type, otherwise simply call the second overload with that type.

And that's all. Nothing fancy, just emulating an explicit `Include` / `ThenInclude` call chains via reflection.

Comment: @InvalidOperationException: `Sequence contains more than one matching element
System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowMoreThanOneMatchException()
System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate, out bool found)
System.Linq.Enumerable.Single<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
IncludeExtensions..cctor() in IncludeExtensions.cs
+
        private static readonly MethodInfo IncludeMethodInfo = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions).GetTypeInfo()`

Answer (score 3):

String-based `Include()` shipped in EF Core 1.1. I would suggest you try upgrading and removing any workarounds you had to add to your code to address this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an "IncludeAll" extension on query will require a different approach from what you have initially done.

EF Core does [expression interpretation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics/). When it sees the `.Include` method, it interprets this expression into creating additional queries. (See [RelationalQueryModelVisitor.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/Query/RelationalQueryModelVisitor.cs#L334-L351) and [IncludeExpressionVisitor.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/Query/ExpressionVisitors/Internal/IncludeExpressionVisitor.cs)).

One approach would be to add an additional expression visitor that handles your IncludeAll extension. Another (and probably better) approach would be to interpret the expression tree from .IncludeAll to the appropriate `.Includes` and then let EF handle the includes normally. An implementation of either is non-trivial and beyond the scope of a SO answer.

Comment: I went for this approach as a simplest way to make this work. Basically, I am defining a "mapper" which says: p1 => p1.P2 is for "P2", p1 => p1.P3 is for "P3" ... So when I receive a String expand = "P2,P3" I am able to get the expressions p1 => p1.P2 and p1 => p1.P3 ... Then I just need to run the includes with them ... But that has been my problem ...

Answer (score 0):

String-based Include() shipped in EF Core 1.1. If you keep this extension you will get error "Ambiguous match found". I spent half day to search solution for this error. Finally i removed above extension and error was resolved.